# C++ pretty stack traces

Tags: c++

I'm on a mac and I'm using clang++ (aliased to g++).

I'm trying to print Python-like stacktraces in C++.

I'm open to to using frameworks and/or other compilers, but I need it to run on a mac or ubuntu.

I have checked out [backtrace](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/backtrace.3.html), but it seems a bit raw -- I would rather not have to count bytes to find out where in the source each line in the stacktrace is referring to.

Also, in case it is relevant, I don't really need any optimizations, so I'm willing to turn off optimizations if it helps. Also, I would prefer it if I could use C++11 features (in case you suggest that I use a different compiler).

---

As a simple example of what I'd like to be able to do, ideally I would run

```
g++ MySource.cpp -o MyProgram <magic options>
```

MySource.cpp might look like

```
#include "MyHeader.hpp"

int main() {
  test();
}
```

MyHeader.hpp might look like

```
#include <magic_print_stacktrace_library>

void test() {
  magic_print_stacktrace_function();
}
```

And if I were to run `./MyProgram` I would like to see something like

```
File "MyHeader.hpp", line 4, in test
  magic_print_stack_tracefunction();
File "MySource.cpp", line 4, in main
  test();
```

Comment: "I would rather not have to count bytes to find out where in the source each line in the stacktrace is referring to" -- and yet, since no such feature is standardized in the language, you are required to use system-specific interfaces like this one.  :(

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code I've used for creating backtraces with backtrace(3):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <execinfo.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/*
 * call external program addr2line WITHOUT using malloc or stdio or anything
 * else that might be problematic if there's memory corruption or exhaustion
 */
const char *addr2line(void *addr, const char *text)
{
    int pfd[2], len;
    pid_t child;
    static char     buffer[1024], *p;
    const char *argv[5] = { "addr2line", buffer, "-e", program_name, 0 };
    uintptr_t a = (uintptr_t)addr;
    if (pipe(pfd) < 0) return 0;
    p = buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1;
    *p = 0;
    while (p > buffer) {
        *--p = "0123456789abcdef"[a&0xf];
        if (!(a >>= 4)) break; }
    argv[1] = p;
    if (text && (p = (char *)strchr(text, '('))) {
        strncpy(buffer, text, p-text);
        buffer[p-text] = 0;
        argv[3] = buffer; }
    while ((child = fork()) == -1 && errno == EAGAIN);
    if (child == -1) return 0;
    if (child == 0) {
        dup2(pfd[1], 1);
        dup2(pfd[1], 2);
        close(pfd[0]);
        close(pfd[1]);
        execvp(argv[0], (char*const*)argv);
        _exit(-1); }
    close(pfd[1]);
    p = buffer;
    while (p < buffer + sizeof(buffer) - 1 &&
           (len = read(pfd[0], p, buffer+sizeof(buffer)-p-1)) > 0 &&
           (p += len) && !memchr(p-len, '\n', len));
    close(pfd[0]);
    waitpid(child, &len, WNOHANG);
    *p = 0;
    if ((p = strchr(buffer, '\n'))) *p = 0;
    if (buffer[0] == 0 || buffer[0] == '?')
        return 0;
    return buffer;
}


void stacktrace() {
    static void *buffer[64];
    int size = backtrace(buffer, 64);
    char **strings = backtrace_symbols(buffer, size);
    for (int i = 1; i < size; i++) {
        if (strings)
            std::endl << "  " << strings[i] << std::endl;
        if (const char *line = addr2line(buffer[i], strings ? strings[i] : 0))          
            std::cerr << "    " << line << std::endl; }
    if (size < 1)
        std::cerr << "backtrace failed" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that it needs to know the path the executable (`program_name` above), and it needs to have been built with `-g` for full info.